# Meteor: able logged in user to remove document from their search results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I want to create the function so when a logged in user scrolls through blog posts, they can click a 'x' button which removes the post from the results instantly, and that post will not yield in future search results for that particular user.

This is what I have so far and it works in terms of the 'x' button retrieving the doc ID of the post. I then inserted this id into an array field called...

```
not_intereted[],
```

This field is in the user profile.

```
Accounts.createUser({
    email: template.find("#signup-email").value,
    password: template.find("#signup-password").value,
    profile: {
      not_interested: []} });
```

Each user is subscribed to the entire post collection.

```
AllPosts = new Meteor.Collection('allposts')
```

For each post rendered, there is a delete button which fires the following event when clicked. This event successfully retrieves the selected document _id into the variable 'a'. This variable successfully is passed to the method.

```
Template.postBoard.events({
'click a.close': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set("selectedPostId", this._id);
    var a = Session.get('selectedPostId');
    Meteor.call('addToremoveList', a);
}
});
```

On the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
'addToremoveList': function(a){
  Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $addToSet: { 'profile.not_interested': a }} );
}
});
```

What I have so far works. I am able to store the document ID that the user wishes to delete. The ID is stored into an array located in the users profile field named `not_interested`.

QUESTION: How can I eliminate these `not_interested` documents when invoking `AllPosts.find();

Im unsure how to implement mongos `$ne` function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the mongo nin operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin

Keep all users subscribed to the entire posts collection. Then, on the client, select the posts you want to display (perhaps using iron router's data functionality) by doing:

```
selectedPosts: AllPosts.find({_id: {$nin: Meteor.user().profile.not_interested} })
```

(I didn't test this, but it should work. Please leave a comment if it doesn't.)

Comment: For test purposes, I placed the code inside a helper and it works. Brilliant, but can you guide me into how to write this within iron-router. Assuming 'allPostsTemplate' as the template name.

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#data

. Basically what you do is inside your route you do data:{selectedPosts: AllPosts.find({_id: {$nin: Meteor.user().profile.not_interested} })} and use selectedPosts just like you would when you used a helper function.

Comment: The code worked with the following within the router... data: function() { return {selectedPosts: AllPosts.find({_id: {$nin: Meteor.user().profile.not_interested} })} } Thank you fritzi2000